Downloading File from Sonatype Nexus and Uploading it to SFTP server using Jenkins Pipeline
Hello,
I have some files that I want to download from Sonatype Nexus repo and upload it to my SFTP server using a Jenkins pipeline. The repo and the server are all running internally (on the local network).
My Jenkins is running inside a Docker container.
Below is my current pipeline script:
    stage('Pull the file off Nexus') {
        withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'REDACTED ID', variable: 'NEXUS_CREDENTIALS')]) {
            sh script: '''
            curl -u ${NEXUS_CREDENTIALS} -o maven-metadata.xml "PATH TO FILE in NEXUS"
            '''
        }
    }
stage('Upload file(s) to server') {
            withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'REDACTED ID', variable: 'FTP_CREDENTIALS')]) {
            sh script: '''
            # Extract username and password from FTP_CREDENTIALS
            USERNAME=$(echo ${FTP_CREDENTIALS} | cut -d: -f1)
            PASSWORD=$(echo ${FTP_CREDENTIALS} | cut -d: -f2)
            SERVER=IP_ADDRESS
            REMOTE_DIR=/home/peter/deploy/
            FILE=maven-metadata.xml

            # Print extracted values for debugging
            echo "USERNAME=${USERNAME}"
            echo "PASSWORD=${PASSWORD}"
            
            # Use sftp with a batch mode
            echo "Uploading $FILE to $SERVER"
            sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPasswordAuthentication=yes ${USERNAME}@${SERVER} << EOF
            cd $REMOTE_DIR
            put $FILE
            bye
            EOF
            '''
        }

    }
}


Downloading the file from Nexus to Jenkins works as expected but the second portion continues to have an error. Below is the error message:
Started by user admin
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/jenkins_home/workspace/nexus_test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Pull the file off Nexus)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $NEXUS_CREDENTIALS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ curl -u **** -o maven-metadata.xml PATH_TO_FILE_ON_NEXUS
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100   284  100   284    0     0  30017      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 31555
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Upload file(s) to server)
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $FTP_CREDENTIALS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo ****
+ cut -d: -f1
+ USERNAME=REDACTED
+ echo ****
+ cut -d: -f2
+ PASSWORD=REDACTED
+ SERVER=IP_ADDRESS
+ REMOTE_DIR=/home/peter/deploy/
+ FILE=maven-metadata.xml
+ echo USERNAME=REDACTED
USERNAME=REDACTED
+ echo PASSWORD=REDACTED
PASSWORD=REDACTED
+ echo Uploading maven-metadata.xml to IP_ADDRESS
Uploading maven-metadata.xml to IP_ADDRESS
+ sftp -oBatchMode=no -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oPasswordAuthentication=yes REDACTED@IP_ADDRESS
Warning: Permanently added 'IP_ADDRESS' (ED25519) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
REDACTED@IP_ADDRESS: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

Connection closed.  
Connection closed
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 255
Finished: FAILURE

As this is my first time with shell scripting and working with Jenkins, any help will be appreciated.
Thank you
